# how does re.compile perform a find_all function in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In reviewing a solution for building csv's out of html tables I stumbled across this bit of code

ol = map(cell_text, row.find_all **(re.compile('t[dh]')))**

What exactly is going on in the bolded text? find_all makes calls for html elements and tags. How does the bolded text achieves that?

*context below*

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import re
import csv

def cell_text(cell):
    return " ".join(cell.stripped_strings)

soup = BeautifulSoup(sys.stdin.read())
output = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        col = map(cell_text, row.find_all(re.compile('t[dh]')))
        output.writerow(col)
    output.writerow([])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It finds all t's followed by d's or h's. `re.compile` simply returns the "compiled" regex object, which `find_all` consumes.

Here's the doc for [re.compile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=re%20compile#re.compile); and BeautifulSoup's `find_all` can take a regex; here's a [sample from the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression):

```
for tag in soup.find_all(re.compile("^b")):
    print(tag.name)
```

Used very similarly, as you can see